# How do I Target New API Level Requirement for App I want to Publish

Tags: android, android-api-levels

How do I Target New API Level Requirement for App I want to publish

Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or create a baseline to see only new errors.
To create a baseline, run `gradlew updateLintBaseline` after adding the following to the module's build.gradle file:

```
android {
lint {
baseline = file("lint-baseline.xml")
}
}
```

For more details, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#snapshot

C:\Users\lferg\AndroidStudioProjects\simple-web-browser-android\app\build.gradle:11: Error: Google Play requires that apps target API level 33 or higher. [ExpiredTargetSdkVersion]
targetSdkVersion 29

```
Explanation for issues of type "ExpiredTargetSdkVersion":
Configuring your app to target a recent API level ensures that users
benefit from significant security and performance improvements, while still
allowing your app to run on older Android versions (down to the
minSdkVersion).

To update your targetSdkVersion, follow the steps from "Meeting Google Play
requirements for target API level",
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.
html

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.html

1 errors, 0 warnings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRr8r.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqBwG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt3lp.png)
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to **34** inside your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion 'xx.y.z'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 34
        /....
    }
```